# How can I get only the first class of an element?

Tags: jquery, substring, this

I am trying to get the class of an element upon hovering on it.

So far I have managed to get a bit of progress:

```
var classString = $(this).attr('class');
```

This gives me all the classes of the element (unfortunately more than one). For instance, if I do:

```
alert(classString);
```

I get the string "blog button main". I want to get just the first word of that string (the first class). I've tried:

```
var myClass = $(classString).text().split(' ')[0];
alert(myClass);
```

expecting to get just "blog", but I get an empty string. I'm sure this is just a basic mistake I am making, but I can't see it.

Comment: Remove .text() and I believe this may work. Text is actually a getter for inner blocks of html, not something that forces an object into a string, like toString(..)

Comment: $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0]

Comment: @rob Why are you making a jQuery object again?

Comment: If you're just trying to check if that class is there you might want jQuery's hasClass method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`classString` is already a string and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a prototype function of a string, not a jQuery function.

```
var classString = $(this).attr('class'); // "blog button main"
var myClass = classString.split(' ')[0]; // "blog"
alert(myClass);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d927r9z4/

---

If you run

```
var classArray = classString.split(' ');
console.log(classArray);
```

You'll get an array of the classes:

```
["blog","button","main"]
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d927r9z4/1/

---

### But it can be faster:

If you use the vanilla JS `classList`, it is much faster

```
var myClass = this.classList[0];
alert(myClass);
```

This way, you don't have to create a jQuery object (slow) or split a string (slow).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d927r9z4/2/

Comment: also `document.querySelector('#elem').classList[0]`
or `$(elem).get(0).classList[0]`

Comment: I'm still a little weary of deploying `querySelector` due to low IE8 support. (See http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

You just want `$(".question-page").attr("class").split(' ')[0]`. Using `.attr("class")` will return you a string with all of the classes separated by a space. You want the first so you can split this string by space to get an array with all of the classes, then select the first (0th) index of that array.

Answer (score 0):

A long time a need something like that, where i tried to get a class when hover a div.

HTML

```
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-first show-more-cards">
   <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
     <p>My code</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).on( 'mouseleave', 'div.views-row ', function( e ) {
        var $tarjeta = $(e.target).closest( '.views-row' ).attr( 'class' ).split(' ')[ 1 ];
});
```

You can look my code where i get the second class.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLMgzj?editors=1111

I hope can i help you.